# Marking source code with a compatible Python version

Tags: python, version, compatibility

Is it possible to mark or label (not just with comments) source code with a python version to indicate which version of python it is compatible with and raise an error or warning when it is run with an older or incompatible python interpreter?

**Edit:**

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 8): 
    raise Exception("You need Python 3.8+")
```

This should do what I want.

Comment: you can use `sys.version_info` to recognize used Python and raise error. And usually it is used at the beginning of code. ie. `sys.version_info.major >= 3 and sys.version_info.minor > 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 8): 
    raise Exception("You need Python 3.8+")
```

This should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.version_info` to recognize what version is used to run code and raise error.

Usually it is used at script beginning.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3 or sys.version_info.minor < 8:
    raise Exception("You need Python 3.8+")
```

It can be used also to import different modules in different versions.

Comment: I can see how your answer will work but will it break in the future with Python 4.0. I think I have found a similar check but will not break in 4.X versions of Python. if sys.version_info < (3, 8): raise Exception("You need Python 3.8+")